# Namespaced nested controller returns route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a namespaced controller Insurances like this:

```
class Modules::Insurance::InsurancesController < ApplicationController
```

In the roues.rb I have this:

```
  namespace :modules do
      namespace :insurance do
          resources :insurances
      end
  end
```

Which gives me the route: modules_insurance_insurances_path
When I create a link however, it returns the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"modules/insurance/users"}
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: how is your folder structure?

Comment: This is the link: link_to I18n.t(:nav_insurance), modules_insurance_insurances_path

Comment: And the folder structure is "app/controllers/modules/insurance/InsurancesController" and "app/models/insurance/Insurance"

Comment: Ok, seems the problem doesn't lie here. You should have a route written before this one which handles the request (rule is first match, first served)

Comment: When I move the namespace block to the top of routes.rb, it gives the same error. Very strange it connects users to a model/insurance route. Could it be insurance/insurances is almost the same name for folder and controller?

Comment: You do `modules_insurance_insurances_path(obj)`. It appears `obj` is of type User.

Comment: I surely miss something but I don't understand the issue as it is exposed now.

Comment: This is the exact output of rake routes: modules_insurance_insurances GET    /modules/insurance/insurances(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"modules/insurance/insurances"} Setting the "obj" is not something I have or can do I think? And by the way, thanks for all the help so far, really appreciated!

Comment: where does this `/users` stuff come from?!

Comment: Good question, now we need an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Apparantly the routes error was caused by another link on that page:

```
link_to "users", :controller => "users", :action => "index"
```

Changing that to

```
link_to "users", users_path
```

solved the problem. Now is a link with :controller and :action not the way you should do this, but I find it strange that it causes a routes error on a link to "modules_insurance_insurances_path"....

Comment: When you specify arguments like `:controller => "users, :actions => "index"`, Rails may guess that you are referring to a controller that is inside current namespace (namely `modules/insurance`), and therefore you got such error messages - and pay attention, it is saying `No route matches {:controller=>"modules/insurance/users"}`, NOT `No route matches {:controller=>"modules/insurance/insurances"}`, so it is obviously not caused by the call to modules_insurance_insurances_path.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
map.with_options :controller => 'modules/insurance/insurances' do |insurance|
   insurance.user_home 'insurance/user', :action => 'users'
end
```

Comment: which rails version you are using?